# Oracle current_timestamp method stores timestamp column values with GMT timezone instead of local timezone

Tags: oracle, timezone

Column is defined as of type Timestamp:

> CREATE_TS                      NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)

While doing an insert we use Oracle CURRENT_TIMESTAMP method to store the timestamp data.
The database is set with EST/EDT timezone:

> SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

| SESSIONTIMEZONE | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| America/New_York | 08-JUN-22 12.40.26.305481000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK |

Data stored with GMT timezone, can someone please provide if there is any explanation/suggestions this is causing?|

Comment: I'm not seeing in your question anything that shows a GMT timezone.  Can you post a complete reproducible example that demonstrates the problem you're describing?

Answer (score 0):

- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the timestamp based on the time zone of the client.
- `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the timestamp based on the time zone of the server's operating system.

If you `INSERT` data from a client application that is configured to be in the `GMT` time zone then when you use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` you will get a `GMT` time zone.

If you want to use the server's time zone and not the client's then use `SYSTIMESTAMP`.